# Extend the attach() method?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've trying to add an attribute to the attach() method in a `belongsTo` relation, but it has no affect:

```
// User Model
class User extends Eloquent {
  public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(`App\Role`);
  }
}

// Role Model
class Role extends Eloquent {
  public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(`App\User`);
  }

  public function attach($id, array $attributes = [], $touch = true){
    $attributes['foo'] = 'bar';
    parent::attach($id, $attributes, $touch);
  }
}
```

When I do `$user->roles()->attach($id, ['key' => 'value']);` - the `['key' => 'value']` is there but it doesn't have the `['foo' => 'bar']` that I've set in the extended attach method (which I believe isn't being called).

Comment: `attach()` is a method on the `BelongsToMany` relationship, not on `BelongsTo` or the model. The code you've posted should be throwing an exception. Additionally, you've tagged laravel-5, but extending the `Eloquent` class looks like laravel 4 code.

Comment: attach is an inbuilt method in laravel that is use with many to many relation, I am not getting why are you creating this function

Comment: I've updated the code to use `belongsToMany` - I'm actually using polymorphic relations (but their classes are extended from `belongsToMany`) - I'm still looking for a way to extend that `attach()` method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to use the attach method **only** if you're working with a many-to-many relationship.

More info here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships

So, you have two different choices:

- you want to work on the *one-to-many* relationship. In this case, you'll have to extend the *save()* method or *saveMany* method. And you will have to work on the [HasMany](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html#method_save) class;
- you want to work on the *many-to-many* relationship. In this case yes, you'll have to work on *attach()*, but in the [BelongsToMany](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_attach) class;

Comment: Thanks for this; I am working on a `morphsMany` (which extends `belongsToMany`) - my issue is that the `attach()` method I've declared in my model isn't actually called.

Comment: Because you shouldn't define _attach_ in the model, but in the relationship class you want to use :)

Comment: Ah yeah - but I don't really want to edit the vendor (class) files; it's a pain then to keep up to date - especially if there's security updates etc.

Comment: You should never edit an existing class. Extend it and use the estension wherever you want :)

Comment: That's the issue I'm at - how do I extend the `belongsToMany` - as `Eloquent\Model` calls it and they're both vendor classes; I don't really want to tapping into Service Providers/Containers to extend just one (`attach()`) method...

Comment: Extend your relationship class, then extend your base model in order to use that new relationhip and finally let your specific model extend your new base model :)